# Extract duplicates from nested list in SML

Tags: list, sml, duplicates, smlnj

I have a function in SML that returns a nested list:

```
[["A", "B", "C"], ["A", "B"], ["B", "C"]]]
```

Is it possible to extract the elements that appear in these lists? i.e. output "B"?

I've tried something to the effect of `List.filter (fn y=>(fn x=> x=y)) lst` but to no avail..
Any hints?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want. You say "extract duplicates" - do you mean things that are in all the sublists? Things that appear more than once? At any rate, outputting a single value doesn't seem to make sense, since there may be more than one value that appears in all the lists.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that the example nested list you give is representative, i.e., that elements are unique and ordered. I'll additionally leave out any explicit types or parameterized comparison functions, so the functions will operate on integers, not strings.

First, break down the problem down into comparing lists pairwise. Define a helper function `common` to find the common elements of a pair of ordered lists. It could look like this:

```
fun common(xs, []) = []
  | common([], ys) = []
  | common(x::xs, y::ys) = if x=y then x::common(xs, ys) 
                           else if x < y then common(xs, y::ys) 
                           else common(x::xs, ys)
```

It has type `int list * int list -> int list`.

To make this work for the nested list, you can base a solution on `common`, along the lines of:

```
fun nested_common([]) = []
  | nested_common(x::[]) = x
  | nested_common(x::y::rest) = nested_common(common(x,y)::rest)
```

This has type `int list list -> int list`.

Putting it to use (in Moscow ML):

```
- nested_common [[1,2,3], [1,2], [2,3]];
> val it = [2] : int list
```